# Runtime creation of tables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I my application "When a button is clicked it should create a new text field in the table". So i have done like this and its not working as well. So what could be the problem in the following snippet.

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var newtr=document.createElement("tr");
    var newtd=document.createElement("td"); 
    var output="<input type=\"textfield\"";
    newtd.innerHtml=output;
    newtr.appendChild(newtd);
    function create_row()
    {
        document.getElementById("table1").appendChild(newtr);
    }
</script>


<body>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type-"textfield" name="tfield">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <input type="button" name="button" value="new row" onclick="create_row();">
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using IE7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few remarks about your code:

1. You need to properly close tags: `var output="<input type=\"textfield\""` is not valid
2. There's no input `type="textfield"` defined
3. The property to set the html of a given DOM element is called `innerHTML` and not `innerHtml`
4. You need to create a new `tr` element every time the button is clicked, so this should be inside the `create_row` function
5. You have a typo in your HTML: `<input type-"textfield" name="tfield">`. This should be changed to `<input type="text" name="tfield" />`
6. You are missing a `head` section in your document

I've tried cleaning your code a bit:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function create_row()
    {
        var newtr = document.createElement('tr');
        var newtd = document.createElement('td');     
        var output = '<input type="text" name="test" />';
        newtd.innerHTML = output;
        newtr.appendChild(newtd);
        document.getElementById('table1').appendChild(newtr);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="textfield" name="tfield" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" name="button" value="new row" onclick="create_row();" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

UPDATE:

As pointed out by [Guffa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893258/runtime-creation-of-tables-in-javascript/1893281#1893281) and [Serkan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893258/runtime-creation-of-tables-in-javascript/1893362#1893362) answers in IE7 a `tbody` section needs to be used:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function create_row()
    {
        var newtr = document.createElement('tr');
        var newtd = document.createElement('td');     
        var output = '<input type="text" name="test" />';
        newtd.innerHTML = output;
        newtr.appendChild(newtd);
        document.getElementById('tablebody').appendChild(newtr);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table1">
        <tbody id="tablebody">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="textfield" name="tfield" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" name="button" value="new row" onclick="create_row();" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tested this on Google Chrome, Firefox 3.5 and IE8 and it works. Don't have IE7 to test. Did you get some error when testing under IE7?

Comment: So nothing happens when you click on the button?

Comment: Sorry Darin, Its working fine in Firefox 3.0... I've missed some of the things.. But it is still not working in IE 7 and not showing any errors. If I clicked down the button nothing happens!!!

Comment: Could by any chance javascript be disabled in IE7 or have you noticed a yellow bar at the top saying `To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restructed this web page from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer.`?

Comment: It doesn't work because you are adding the row in the table instead of in the tbody. See the code in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Darin,serkan and guffa for your answers and comments. And i am selecting the darin's answer of pointing out the code standards and the encouragement. Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

In order to make this work in IE you should create a TBODY first then append the TRs in TBODY. If you don't do this IE cannot render the table content, HTML part will be created succesffully but it will not be seen on the page.

So you should modify your script to append TRs into the TBODY

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what solved the problem. I've run this into Compatibility Mode under IE8 which basically simulates IE7 and it didn't work. If I put a `tbody` with an id and use `document.getElementById('idoftbody').appendChild(newtr)` it worked fine. My god, one more reason to use jQuery. +1, this really is the correct answer.

Comment: Dom scripting is really messy on IE. If you are going to manipulate dom in real time I suggest you to use Prototype.js, it has a great DOM scripting support.

Answer (score 3):

- You are missing a head tag.
- The script should be in the head tag.
- The html code for the input element is missing a closing bracket.
- The type "textfield" does not exist.
- The code only works once as you create the elements outside the function.
- The method is innerHTML, not innerHtml.
- You have to add the row to the tbody element, not the table itself.

I have tested this in Firefox 3 and IE 8 and it works:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function create_row() {
      var newtr=document.createElement("tr");
      var newtd=document.createElement("td");     
      var output="<input type=\"text\">";
      newtd.innerHTML=output;
      newtr.appendChild(newtd);
      document.getElementById("table1body").appendChild(newtr);
   }
</script>

</head>
<body>
   <table>
      <tbody id="table1body">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type-"textfield" name="tfield">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> <input type="button" name="button" value="new row" onclick="create_row();">
      </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>

</body>
</html>
```